# Inviting external users to SharePoint site programmatically (C#) is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, permissions, external-sharing

I am trying to invite external users to the SharePoint site programmatically, but I am not receiving the invitation.

When I tried it manually and with PowerShell it worked. But it doesn't really work with C# code:

```
var users = new List<string>() { "sxxxx@gmail.com" };
var userRoles = new List<UserRoleAssignment>();
foreach(var user in users)
{
  UserRoleAssignment role = new UserRoleAssignment();
  role.UserId = user;
  role.Role = Role.View;
  userRoles.Add(role);
}
string message = "Please accept this invite to access our SharePoint Site.";
// Send invitation requests to external users 
WebSharingManager.UpdateWebSharingInformation(context, context.Web, userRoles, true, message, true, true);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am using the same `UpdateWebSharingInformation()` method in PowerShell which works well.

If any one had same issue and resolved it, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I saw above that not contains coding details about Authentication to SharePoint; and the tag topics showing "sharepoint-online" for this case. Please, review the Microsoft Documents about Authentication to SPO from .NET at [Using CSOM for .NET Standard instead of CSOM for .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard). This document contains the best recommendations to implement Authentication code to SharePoint Online, and the code approach contains difference from a trivial approach for .NET Framework Authentication Credentials.